# How does a site that finds the best price among many eshops work ? Like pricegrabber

Tags: php, xml

I saw a website http://www.pricegrabber.com/nokia/products.html/form_keyword=nokia/st=query/sv=findit_top/ that finds the cheaper/best price of a product among many eshops. Their system searches through their database (I guess they are using XML) and displays all shops that have the product sorted by price.

I believe that their search function looks over a united XML of all the shops. But my question is, isn't supposed all those eshops that include in the site, should have the same XML structure? How do they manage to do it ?

If my idea is wrong please tell me how does this can work.

Comment: They probably put all the XML files into their own database and then use their tables to get all the prices.

Comment: Using php and xslt to rename the elements of 10 XMLs to your needs every 1 hour is a no no ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The nice way is to get XML data from each shop and then group everything to display to the user. Since there is no standard format for this, your site must have a specific backend for each shop.

Comment: You mean by creating a PHP script that gets a list/array of XMLs and renames all the for example "title", "product" "name" "item" to "ProductName" through XLST and creates a new XML file that contains the new data ? Then their search function will search the XML for "ProductName" right ?

Comment: I meant that you need a script for each shop to convert its specific data to a standard (as defined by you) format by any means, so that you can later use the data easily

Answer (score 1):

Often, the sites being compared willingly offer up their prices to the comparison site (via an API, webservice etc.) rather than getting scraped against their will.

From their perspective, anything that draws some extra visibility is a good thing. They normally pay the comparison site a small affiliate fee for every sale/customer that is referred to them as well.

GoCompare, CompareTheMarket et. al. don't exist to be helpful out of their own good nature - they are getting a cut of profits and the sites they feature are complicit in providing them with the data.

Comment: Yes I also think that scrapping is not a good solution. Thank you for the info.

Answer (score 0):

Each web sites submits a csv file with all their product information in the same format to pricegrabber. Pricegrabber then imports that data.

You can do the same by signing up a to an affiliate network and like CJ. Once you have an account you can download product data feeds from merchants that provide them. You will need to match up any item with the same SKU or by brand and MPN. Matching the same item to different merchants is the hard part.