# How do the price-compare apps get the products info and the price data?

Tags: android, iphone, ios

Thare are many apps and sites can compare the prices of the same products at different places like different sites and different supermarkets,how do they get the products infomation and the price data?

Thank you!

Comment: possible duplicate of [How does a site that finds the best price among many eshops work ? Like pricegrabber](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6424571/how-does-a-site-that-finds-the-best-price-among-many-eshops-work-like-pricegrab)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

More often than not, through APIs provided to them by the merchants themselves.

See my answer here: [How does a site that finds the best price among many eshops work ? Like pricegrabber](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6424571/how-does-a-site-that-finds-the-best-price-among-many-eshops-work-like-pricegrab/6424799#6424799)

Answer (score 2):

Mostly via partnerships. However, screen scraping (web crawling) etc. are also viable ways.